# How to use linear approximation to estimate $2\ln(1.1)+3$?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone please share how to solve this?

The question is to use the linear approximation to estimate $2\ln(1.1)+3$

The hint given to me was to find f(x) first and find a and f'(a) but I can't follow the hint and don't know how to find those.
Thanks.
I have not tried anything because I am lost at how to find f(x)first or a.
We have only been doing answers where the original f(x) is given then I find the linear approximation and estimate certain values afterwards. This is the first time the f(x) is not provided to me.

Comment: $\ln(1+x)\sim x$ as $x\sim 0$, so $\ln 1.1\sim 0.1$. Thus $2\ln 1.1+3\approx 3.2$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, we have the following formula for the linear approximation of f(x) at a point $x=a$:

$f(x) ≈f(a) + f'(a)(x - a)$

The nearest value to $1.1$ that is easy to compute is $x=1$ as we know $\ln(1)=0$

If $f(x) = \ln (x)$ and $a = 1$, we get:

$\ln(x) = \ln (1) + x - 1=x-1$

If we set $x=1.1$ we can approximate $\ln(1.1)$ by $1.1-1=0.1$, we can multiply it by $2$ now and get $0.2$, then we add $3$ to it as we need $2\ln(1.1)+3$ and get $3.2$ as our approximation.

Actual value is $2\ln(1.1)+3=3.1906...$ so we are pretty close.

Comment: If you need more precision you can always use the MacLaurin Series $\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^3}3-\frac{x^4}4+\cdots$. Just plug in $x=0.1$. Since $0.1\in(-1,1)$, by using a finite number of terms in the series you should get a good approximation of what $\ln(1.1)$ is.

Comment: Good suggestion, IF I remember some of my calculus correctly the error will be $\leq$ the next term(someone correct me if I am wrong), so since I used the first time my error will be $\leq \frac{0.1^2}{2}=0.005$

Comment: Note that that is the error in approximation $\ln(1.1)$ with $0.1$ and not the whole thing

Comment: @sergio Thank you. This is the exact approach the instructor wanted us to take. But I was not able to come up with this. I will see if I can get my post to reopen and accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

The tangent to a curve, which is the best linear approximation around the contact point, is the line through the contact point, with a slope equal to the derivative at the contact point.

Use a contact point near $1.1$ that is easy to compute.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the strategy for it just don't know how to apply it to this question.

Comment: @Scarlett: do seriously consider my hints.